# NewtworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl()

Tags: android

I am doing an Udacity course (https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud851/lessons/e5d74e43-743c-455e-9a70-7545a2da9783) and I have to implement the following code:

```
  public class GithubQueryTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {

    // TODO (26) Override onPreExecute to set the loading indicator to visible

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {
        URL searchUrl = params[0];
        String githubSearchResults = null;
        try {
            githubSearchResults = NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(searchUrl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return githubSearchResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String githubSearchResults) {
        // TODO (27) As soon as the loading is complete, hide the loading indicator
        if (githubSearchResults != null && !githubSearchResults.equals("")) {
            // TODO (17) Call showJsonDataView if we have valid, non-null results
            mSearchResultsTextView.setText(githubSearchResults);
        }
        // TODO (16) Call showErrorMessage if the result is null in onPostExecute
    }
}
```

At the line  "githubSearchResults = NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(searchUrl);" I get an cannot resolve error for NetworkUtils. What to do?

Comment: Have you imported the correct package ?

Comment: You have to post your <code>NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl</code> implementation just to obtain the full picture :)

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check if NetworkUtils class is there in your project. Or if it is imported via gradle depedancy, check if the class is imported.

Comment: Hm not it's not, but usually classes get imported automatically with alt+enter, why not this one?

Also i have now pasted import com.domain.android.name.utilities.NetworkUtils; and now it can't resolve android.

Comment: ok, check if NetworkUtils.java class is there in your project.

to check, do ctrl+shift+N and in the dialog box type networkutils

If the file appears with the name networkutils, means it exists, else not.

Tell me if it exists..

Comment: Oh yeah that thing is missing. I never downloaded their GitHub code as I wanted to create something that's not exactly the same as an weather app, but similar and they never mentioned that some of the code was not in MainActivity. So I just have to remove NetworkUtils. from the code. Is there any downside if I do it this way instead of creating a new class?

Comment: the code to download the data from the URL is being called from the NetworkUtils class within its method getResponseFromHttpUrl. So either you need to copy the implementation of this method and insert it in this class and call it instead of NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(searchUrl), Or u need to include that class as well inside the project.

Comment: >copy the implementation of this method and insert it in this class and call it >instead of NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(searchUrl)

Yeah that's what I've done. Are there any downsides to this?

Comment: No, the code will work fine. Its just that the code becomes less cohesive by putting all the code in one class. So as a best practice try making it cohesive so that the class only does what it should do, like NetworkUtils handles all network calls, and so on.